# How to call constructor with nested generic in java

Tags: java, generics

I got the following class:

```
public class Repository<T> extends ExternalRepository<Wrapper<T>> 
{
    public Repository(Class<Wrapper<T>> type, DB db) 
    {
        super(type, db);
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to call the construtor since

```
new Repository(Wrapper<SomeClass>.class, dbInstance)
```

does not work. So what can I do? I can change the Repository class if necessary.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the class instance for `Wrapper<SomeClass>` directly using `.class` literal. It is not allowed. You can only use it with raw type - `Wrapper.class`, or unbounded wildcard types - `Wrapper<?>.class`.

To get what you want, you've to use some type-casting here:

```
new Repository<SomeClass>((Class<Wrapper<SomeClass>>)(Class<?>)Wrapper.class, 
                           dbInstance)
```

This first cast a `Class<Wrapper>` to a `Class<?>`, which is an unbounded wildcard reference. And then that reference can be type-casted to `Class<Wrapper<SomeClass>>`.

Also, don't forget to give the type argument while creating an instance of your generic class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works :-) Any suggestions on improvements?

Comment: Why not simplifying the constructor like `public Repository(Class<T> type, DB db)` and use it like `new Repository(SomeClass.class, db)` ?

Comment: @AndreiNicusan how would I than call the super constructor?

Comment: @Tarken I can't think of any easier way, if you want to pass a `Class<Wrapper<T>>`. No.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

```
new Repository(Wrapper.class, dbInstance);
```

There's only one `class` descriptor for each generic class, including `Wrapper`.

Comment: How does one avoid the compiler warning?

Comment: It won't work. The method expects `Class<Wrapper<T>>`./

Comment: As far as the compilation is concerned, it won't fail (tested). But indeed, it will instantiate a raw `Repository`, which will generate a warning.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan Are you sure you tested it with `Class<Wrapper<T>>`? It fails at least on my machine.